# Android. Radiobutton text won't display correctly

Tags: android

I have the below xml code which i use to display inside a Dialog. The problem is that the letter "E" in "Easy" is displayed under the radio button itself. So it's not visible. Why is that? The rest are shown correctly, on the right side of each corresponding RadioButton.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioBtnEasy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Easy"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioBtnMedium"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Medium"            
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioBtnHard"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hard"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</RadioGroup>
```

**EDIT**

At Padma Kumar's request, i post the rest of the code. This is how i display the dialog. I made the dialog's width to fit the screen's width, and not wrap around the content. 
I removed this, but it still displayed the Easy text incorrectly.

```
    //Define a new dialog window
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    //Load the predefined layout onto this dialog
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.new_session_dialog);
    //Set title of dialog
    dialog.setTitle("Create new session");
    //Set the width of the dialog to fill the width of the screen 
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    //Show the dialog
    dialog.show();
```

Comment: simply put an space like this  android:text="  Easy"  there are other solution too but with this way you dont have to choose any other android tag like padding ,,etc

Comment: your code is working fine for me. post other content what you are adding there.

Comment: @Padma Kumar. Except for this: `dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);` which i use to set the width of the dialog to match the screen, there isn't any other code.

Comment: @Vipin Sahu. Yes, i came up with the same solution, but i'd really like to know the cause for this, and repair it :)

Comment: it may be because you are using radio group as parent layout for your all radio button , I think you may use android:layout_margin="2dp" for radio button so that the radio group may not fill that space .....

Comment: @Vipin Sahy, nope, that didn't do anything :(

Comment: hmm. I've just tested it on a ldpi device, and it displays it correctly. It goes nuts only on hdpi :(( Oh COME ON !! And if i use your advice Vipin Sahu, and place a space before the text, on the ldpi device it will display it way off :))

Comment: Hey @AndreiBogdan Radio Group is a Linear Layout so if you want to you can remove linear layout and use only radio group and the set the attribute android:ems="", you can also use android:padding="";

Comment: use the android:ems attribute it but manage your text on all density device .........

Comment: hei Vipin Sahu, write your last commet as an answer, so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the android:ems attribute it but manage your text on all density device

Answer (score 1):

The 0dp width is most likely the issue,

Otherwise if only the first character "E" is not being displayed, put a space before Easy.

Ex)Instead of "Easy" put " Easy"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting this question. I ran into the same problem: the icon in the first radio button stomped on the first letter in the text following it. I am using the Android 1.6 emulator. After I install my app, start my app and display the radio group, I see the problem. However, when I use Back key to take me back to the Home screen and start my app and display the radio group again, I don't see the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove layout_weight=1 first and put fill_parent on RadioButton width. Then do necessary adjustment.